# How can I buffer the output in my threads

Tags: python, multithreading, output, buffer

I want to buffer the output of my threads so that the output is generated *in order*.

This is my code:

```html
from threading import Thread
import time
from random import randint

def func_with_wait_time(wait_time):
    print("First output in Function with wait time:", wait_time)
    time.sleep(wait_time)
    print("Last output in Function with wait time:", wait_time)

threads = []
for i in range(3):
    wait = randint(3, 10)
    thread = Thread(target=func_with_wait_time, args=(wait,))
    threads.append(thread)

for thread in threads:
    thread.start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

And it generates:

```html
First output in Function with wait time: 9
First output in Function with wait time: 3
First output in Function with wait time: 6
Last output in Function with wait time: 3
Last output in Function with wait time: 6
Last output in Function with wait time: 9
```

But I want it to be:

```html
First output in Function with wait time: 9
Last output in Function with wait time: 9
First output in Function with wait time: 3
Last output in Function with wait time: 3
First output in Function with wait time: 6
Last output in Function with wait time: 6
```

How can I tell Python to not send the `print()` text until the end of the thread is reached?

Comment: One way would be to not call print(), but rather append the text to a string.  Then call print() on the string at the end of the thread's execution (or better yet, have the main thread print out the string after the thread has been joined, to avoid any possible race conditions in the printing process)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner That would work but actually be a very work and maintenance intensive solution, right? I would rather just buffer it if possible.

Comment: I can see how having `print()` do the buffering for you would be preferable, but AFAIK the `print()` function doesn't have any per-thread-buffering capabilities.  Hopefully someone who knows more Python than I do will come along and prove me wrong, though :)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I know it from PHP. You can do something like `ob_start()` and `ob_end()` and that does the trick. Looking for something like this in Python.